# What is the measure $ \angle CGE$ and $\angle EGA$ that form the diagonals of the quadrilateral $ECFA$?

Tags: geometry

For reference:

In a convex quadrilateral ABCD (not convex in C) the extensions of sides BC and CD
perpendicularly intersect sides AD and BC respectively.
Calculate the measure of the angles
which form the diagonals of the formed quadrilateral.

My progress:

$\triangle EDC \sim \triangle BFC (A.A.) \implies \measuredangle D = \measuredangle B\\
\measuredangle DCE  =\measuredangle FCB = 90^\circ-\alpha\\
\measuredangle A = 2\theta\\
\measuredangle BCD = 2\alpha+2\theta\\
\measuredangle ECF = 180-(90-\alpha) = 90+\alpha  =\measuredangle BCD \\
\triangle DFA: \alpha + 2\theta = 90^\circ\\
\triangle CEF (isosceles) :\measuredangle GEC = 45-\frac{\alpha}{2} = \measuredangle CEG$

[image]

Something is missing to prove that the Angles are 90 degrees

Comment: I don't think there's enough information... If you move B a little to the right, F changes location, so $\angle G$ changes as well.

Comment: Andria is correct - you may conclude that FEBD is cyclic and have $\alpha$ various values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\widehat {ECG}=\frac{(ECF=90+\alpha)}2=45+\alpha$

$\widehat {ECA}=\widehat {ECG}=45+\frac{\alpha}2$

$\widehat {EAC}=90-(45+\frac{\alpha}2)=45-\frac{\alpha}2$

Therefore:

$\widehat {ECG}=\widehat {AEG}$

that is triangles ECA and EGA are similar, since $\widehat {CEA}=90$, therefore :

$\widehat {EGA}=90^o$

Comment: @sirous--can you explain $\widehat{ECA } = \frac{\widehat{ECG}}{2}?$  ..do you use the symbol "\widehat" for arc or angle?

Comment: Can I say that in the triangle ABD, C is orthocenter (meeting heights) so AC is perpendicular DB, angle CGE will measure 90 degrees because CG will be the height of triangle CEF?

Comment: @petaarantes, sorry for some errors, I corrected. You showed that triangle GEF is isosceles so  quadrilateral BDEF is isosceles trapezoid  so  triangle ABD is alsp isosceles, therefore you can claim that  C is orthocenter  of triangle ABD.

Comment: @petaarantes, widehat is for angle. For arc is: \overset{\LARGE\frown}{FDI} which gives: $\overset{\LARGE\frown}{FDI}$. and means arc FI passing point D, for example.

Comment: @sirousgrateful for the clarifications..the widehat symbol i use for bow, hence the doubt...for angle i use \angle and \measuredangle

Comment: @ sirou$\angle EGC = \angle ECA = 45 +\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and not. $ 45+\alpha $

Comment: @petaarantes, you are right, corrected.

Comment: grateful for the help

Answer (score 1):

Why did you stop? You are almost at the end. $$\angle DCF=180^{\circ}$$ $$\angle DCE+\angle ECF=180^{\circ}$$ $$\angle DCE+2\angle ECG=180^{\circ}$$(from triangle similarity) $$90^{\circ}-\alpha+2\angle ECG=180^{\circ}$$ $$\angle ECG=\frac{90^{\circ}+\alpha}{2}$$ Considering $\triangle ECG$, $$\angle ECG+\angle CEG+\angle EGC=180^{\circ}$$ $$\left(45^{\circ}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+\left(45^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+\angle EGC=180^{\circ}$$ $$\angle ECG=90^{\circ}$$

Comment: grateful for the help